# Electro Optics vs Optoelectronics > What's the difference?

Tags: optoelectronics, physics

I've seen both wikipedias of Electro Optics & Optoelectronics but I'm still confused on what the difference is.

I'm currently pursuing a degree in either Physics or Electrical Engineering because optics,photonics etc and the excitement of attempting to replace electrons in computers and such has sparked my interest.

Electro Optics vs Optoelectronics > What's the difference?

Answer (score 4):

I don't agree with what David has said. If you think about it, the first word defines the type and the second defines the object (warning: these terms are used pretty loosely and are probably incorrect).

In electro-optics, the important word is "optics", while in opto-electronics - the main bit is "electronics". Here's a couple definitions from Wikipedia:

**[Electro-optics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electro-optic_effect)**

> An electro-optic effect is a change in the optical properties of a
>   material in response to an electric field <...>

**[Opto-electronics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optoelectronics)**

> Optoelectronics is the study and application of electronic devices
>   that source, detect and control light <...>

Comment: And you believed what you read on the internet?!?! (note sarcasm.)  The definition of a word is ultimately based on common usage, and common usage of these two terms shows them to be interchangeable.  A quick Google search of these terms will find manufactures of LEDs using both terms.

Comment: IMO, the fact that a wrong term is used commonly does not make it any more right. For example, you can refer to DE-9 connector as DB-9 and people will understand, but technically you'll still be wrong.

Comment: Yes, "Technically you'd still be wrong.", but it doesn't change the fact that you have to consider the terms to be identical (or ambiguous) when used in normal conversation.  Even with your definitions there is ambiguity.  An LCD, for example, could be either an electro-optic device or an opto-electronic device.  In one case the optical properties are changed with an electric field, in the other case it is an electronic device that is controlling the light.

Answer (score 1):

Electro Optics is for dyslexic people.  The rest of us use opto-electronics.

But seriously, they are all the same thing.  Just different way of saying things.  I don't know the reason for the differences (probably an international translation thing), but it doesn't matter since the terms are used interchangeably.

Answer (score 0):

Simply speaking, Electro-Optics is more "optics" and Optoelectronics is more "electronics".

Optoelectronics is still *electronics*, whose purpose/function is related to optics. For example, semiconductor lasers, semiconductor optical amplifiers and semiconductor photodetectors are all *electronic devices*, operated by electrical current/voltage, but their functions is to generate, amplify and detect *optical wave*. They are often referred to as Photonics too.

Electro-Optics refers to controlling optical properties of material using electrical field. This may sounds similar to what Optoelectronics is, but they are very different indeed and they are used in different places. For example, the word "Electro-Optic" is often used with the word "material". Lithium niobate is a very important *Electro-Optic material*, the index of which changes when an electric field is applied. As a result people use Lithium niobate to make optical modulators. But a Lithium niobate modulator is simply a bulk material with electrodes, it is not a electronic device, thus not *Optoelectronic* either. These are NOT interchangeable terms/concepts.

If this is still confusing to you, if not even more confusing, I came up with a simple rule of thumb: If the device involves a semiconductor PN junction (as in any electronic devices), it's *Optoelectronics*; Otherwise, it's *Electro-Optics*.

Comment: I'm not sure about your rule of thumb in the last paragraph. There's too much overlap between these fields to draw a hard line between them. Mach-Zehnder modulators easily fall into both fields, and don't involve a pn-junction.   Liquid crystal displays? MSM photodetectors? poly-Si solar cells?

Comment: @ThePhoton, Very good point. My comment seemed over-simplified the case, but that was the purpose too. And it certainly missed out wide range of devices as you mentioned, but again, if the person who posted the question knows this much of detail, he wouldn't be asking that question. Thanks for mentioning those devices, I completely overlooked them.